# do loose equality comparision using array.includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array.includes does a strict comparison of array elements.

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes(2)); // return true

console.log(array1.includes("2")); // return false
```

But I want the result to return true in second case as well.My main goal is to know whether an array contains an element. Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Comment: Why not just compare the Integer value of your element? `array1.includes(+"2")`

Comment: You could use a custom ‘array.filter’ function and return whether the value is 2 or “2”

Comment: @LukeStoward: No need to build a new array (and keep searching to the end even if already found) just to check whether the array includes a value. :-)

Comment: @Zenoo does the approach you have suggested have any limitations?

Comment: Well, if the String you give isn't the representation of a number, getting its Integer value with `+` will return `NaN`. Other than that, I don't see any down side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't use `includes`, since it always uses strict equality; you can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead:

```
console.log(array1.some(e => e == "2"));
```

`some` calls the callback you provide for the elements, in order, until your callback returns a truthy value, in which case `some` stops looping and returns `true`. If your callback never returns a truthy value (including because it was never called because the array was empty), `some` returns `false`.

`some` was added in ES5 (2009).

Live example:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(array1.some(e => e == "2"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If the array is always formed by numbers and you are sure to pass a string to be checked, you could also use `parseInt()`:

```js
console.log(array1.includes(parseInt("2")));
```

Please note that this would work also if you were to pass an integer to the `parseInt` but that is is not correct since `parseInt` expect a string as a parameter.